# Vertex slide evenly inwards

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, topology, proportional-editing

I know of the feature vertex/edge sliding (g g or shift-v) but it only slides the vertex along one face while in this gif it slides evenly on both faces. How is the even vertex slide done?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a vertex bevel (Ctrl+Shift+B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gif shows a bevel operation.

In edit mode, select the vertex at the corner, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> then, during the bevel operation, use the <kbd>V</kbd> key to apply the bevel op to the vertex.

Comment: You can also start beveling with Shift+Ctrl+B, this way you don't need to press V. //Edit: Oh, @ChristopherBennett already commented that. (I need more coffee)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, yes... I did not know for the 'shift'. Christopher commented it while I was posting the answer. Pro: one step operation. Con: hard to ctrl shift V with one hand (at least, for me).

Comment: Hard with one hand? Really? Sorry, didn't know that. To me it's quite easy... but it's Shift + Ctrl + **B**, maybe even harder than V ;) Or you could use both hands. After you initiated the _Vertex Bevel_ tool you don't need to hold the keys so you can put your hand back on the mouse.